# Tap button programmatically in Windows Phone apps

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have 10 buttons with their name is from "btn1" -> "btn10". I created button6_Click event method like this. But now, I want to invoke the tap event on these button in the Initialize method of my page in my WP Apps. How can I do that, I found that Windows 8 app can do this but on the Windows Phone I can't find anything to perform this action.

Comment: what is the code for `button6_Click` and how do you invoke it in the Initialize method? please add the code. Also, by `Initialize method`, do you mean the page's constructor?

Comment: @kennyzx: Yes that's right, I would like to perform the click on button when my app starting. The code in button6_Click just write some text to the textbox, and I want to call this method in the constructor of my page.

Comment: You can always invoke it like this: `buttin6_Click(this, null)`, like normal method. Depending on what you have inside the method it will success or throw an exception - some things cannot be run in the constructor.